# Return only rows where values do not exist in other table

Tags: plsql

I have **table A** with an Id column.

I have **table B** with an Id1 and Id2 column.

I want to return all rows in **table b** that neither Id1 or Id2 exist in **table A**.  If either Id1 or Id2 in **table b** has a match in **table A**, I want to return that result.

Hence, if **table A** looked like the following:

```
Id    
123
456
789
```

and **table B** looked like the following:

```
Id1 Id2    
123 545
343 432
184 789
```

Row 1 and 3 would not be returned as they each have a match in **table A**.  However, row 2 in **table b** matches on neither column, so it would be returned.

I've been racking my head and can't seem to figure out the query.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Id columns are not null:

```
select * from tableB 
where Id1 not in (select Id from tableA) 
and Id2 not in (select Id from tableA)
```

or

```
select b.* 
from tableB b
left join tableA a1 on b.id1=a1.id
left join tableA a2 on b.id2=a2.id
where a1.id is null and a2.id is null
```

Comment: why query `a` twice ? `select b.* from tableB b left join tableA a on (b.id1=a.id or b.id2=a.id) where coalesce(a.id1,a.id2) is null`

Comment: @haki - Good solution!  You can post it as separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

When looking for records where some data does not *exist* in another table there is always the *exists* clause, hence the name ;-)

```
select * from tableB 
where not exists
(
  select *
  from tableA
  where id in (tableB.id1, tableB.id2)
);
```